# Is that possible to upgrade Nvidia Quadro k1000m with gpu upgrade? (Replacement of N14P-Q1-A2 with N17P-Q1-A2)

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, upgrade, dell-precision, nvidia-quadro

I have Nvidia k1000m on my Dell precision m4700, but it's some kind of weak gpu. After i didn't find Nvidia m2200, m1200 & m1000m graphic cards on the market which all are mxm 3.0 type A just like my own k1000m, i find related gpu of those graphic cards on market.
I am wondering is that possible to just upgrade gpu and get rid of k1000m or not.
Also they have different vram soldered on.
M1200 and m2200m has GDDR5 but k1000m has DDR3.

Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: IMHO M1200, M2200 have different temperature balance (emit more heat) so just replace can be quire risky and you (with high probability) will increase the internal temperature (which is bad for laptops)

Comment: Power consumption for M2200 is 55 watt, 45 watt for M1200 and 40 watt for m1000m while 45 watt for k1000m.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely not feasible.

The VRAM isn't compatible, power-requirements and heat-dissipation are higher. Motherboard and cooling are not designed for that.
And the systems video-bios will probably have no idea what to do with the new GPU.

That is without the concerns about soldering the old GPU out of the motherboard and soldering the new one in. That alone is specialist work not usually feasible for the average hobbyist.

To be honest... That is an old laptop with a 10 year old CPU. Doesn't really make much sense to spend time and effort on a very complicated and most likely non-functional upgrade.
Throw in a SSD and some more RAM, if you have to too. That is relatively cheap and easy without any risk of damaging the laptop beyond repair. The (lack of) video-performance can't be helped.